# PGFPlots: add custom labels to alternative x axis

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ticks

I have the following plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis} [
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
    ylabel={Volume [dB]},
    xmin=10,
    xmax=10000,
    grid=major,
    smooth,
    legend entries={Trumpet, Trombone, Horn, Tuba},
  ]
    \addplot [blue]             table {recordings/Bb-C4.txt};
    \addplot [orange!50!yellow] table {recordings/C-C4.txt};
    \addplot [green!70!black]   table {recordings/Eb-C4.txt};
    \addplot [red]              table {recordings/F-C4.txt};
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It's nice, but while "Frequency" is important to describe here, I would also like to add x-axis ticks and labels for specific frequencies to represent note names.

I feel like I'm close by adding `extra x ticks` to the options of `semilogxaxis`:

```
    extra x ticks = {262, 523, 784, 1047},                                      
    extra x tick labels={C4,   C5,  G5, C6  },                                  
%    extra x tick style={xticklabel=above}
```

[image]

But I'm really struggling with the `extra x tick style`.  These labels need to not interfere with the normal x-tick labels. The answer could be to move them to the top of the plot, but just moving them above the axis might be the best I can do.

Using "two ordinants" (as described in the [pgfplots documentation](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)) seems close to what I want, but it's only described for alternate Y-axis.

[image]

---

Here's a simplified MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis} [
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
    ylabel={Volume [dB]},
    xmin=10,
    xmax=10000,
    grid=major,
    smooth,
    extra x ticks = {262, 523, 784, 1047},
    extra x tick labels={C4,   C5,  G5, C6  }
%    extra x tick style={xticklabel=above}
  ]
    \addplot [blue] coordinates {
      (10,-81)
      (102,-93)
      (204,-87)
      (253,-32)
      (301,-67)
      (355,-77)
      (403,-78)
      (452,-81)
      (500,-74)
      (522,-41)
      (554,-77)
      (602,-83)
      (651,-86)
      (705,-87)
      (753,-88)
      (775,-60)
      (780,-52)
      (785,-56)
      (800,-92)
    };
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which cab be compiled as it is. So far we can't do this since your files with data are unknown. For WME should be sufficient just one `\addplot` macro and data for it

Comment: @Zarko  MWE added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    ylabel={Volume [dB]},
    xmin=10,
    xmax=10000,
    grid=major,
    legend entries={Trumpet, Trombone, Horn, Tuba},
            }
\begin{semilogxaxis} [
    axis x line*=bottom,    % <---
    xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
                        ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10,-81)    (102,-93) (204,-87) (253,-32) (301,-67)
        (355,-77)   (403,-78) (452,-81) (500,-74) (522,-41)
        (554,-77)   (602,-83) (651,-86) (705,-87) (753,-88)
        (775,-60)   (780,-52) (785,-56) (800,-92)
                            };           
\end{semilogxaxis}
\begin{semilogxaxis} [
    axis x line*=top,       % <---
        xtick     = {262, 523, 784, 1047},
        xticklabels = {C4, C5, G5, C6}  
                        ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10,-81)    (102,-93) (204,-87) (253,-32) (301,-67)
        (355,-77)   (403,-78) (452,-81) (500,-74) (522,-41)
        (554,-77)   (602,-83) (651,-86) (705,-87) (753,-88)
        (775,-60)   (780,-52) (785,-56) (800,-92)
                            };
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit(1):**
To second `axis` is now added option `axis y line =none,`. This should allow that `ytick` is written only in the the first `axis` environment.

Sorry, but I can tested its effect with your real data (they are still unknown), so for test I make small variation of coordinates for the second `axis`.

**Edit (2):**
To `\pgfplotsset` are added `axis` options suggested by OP in comment below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    scale only axis,        % <--- added
    xmin=10,    xmax=10000,
    ymin=-100,  ymax=-20,   % <--- added
    ylabel={Volume [dB]},
    no marks,               % <--- added 
every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
    legend entries={Trumpet, Trombone, Horn, Tuba},
            }
\begin{semilogxaxis} [
    axis x line*=bottom,   
    xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
                        ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10,-81)    (102,-93) (204,-87) (253,-32) (301,-67)
        (355,-77)   (403,-78) (452,-81) (500,-74) (522,-41)
        (554,-77)   (602,-83) (651,-86) (705,-87) (753,-88)
        (775,-60)   (780,-52) (785,-56) (800,-92)
                            };           
\end{semilogxaxis}
\begin{semilogxaxis} [
    axis x line*=top,       
    axis y line =none,      % <--- added
        xtick     = {262, 523, 784, 1047},
        xticklabels = {C4, C5, G5, C6}  
                        ]
\addplot +[red] coordinates {   % <--- changed coordinates   
        (10,-51)    (102,-83) (204,-77) (253,-42) (301,-37)
        (355,-87)   (403,-78) (452,-71) (500,-74) (522,-33)
        (554,-55)   (602,-88) (651,-86) (705,-87) (753,-78)
        (775,-54)   (780,-56) (785,-65) (800,-88)
                            };
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like this!  My compilation time is already pretty long,  so I'll experiment to see if I can avoid defining the coordinates twice.

Comment: @Stewart , in your original question you have four `\addplot`s in `axis` environment. So, you can use three of them in the first `axis` environment in and rest one in the second one. On this way you will avoid to calculate any of them twice. This means, that implement of provided solution in your real case will not require that any coordinates need to be calculated twice!

Comment: I tried that, but small difference in the y-values caused two y-scales to be slightly mis-aligned.   I'm playing with `\pgfplotset{set layers}` and `\begin{semilogaxis}[scale only axis, ...]` to try and keep one of the axes empty.  I'll update the answer if I figure that out.  So far, I keep getting `! Missing } inserted.`.  Worst case: duplicating the data isn't the end of the world.  I don't think I need any more help.  Thanks!

Comment: Good call on adding the `axis y line=none`.  I found that was needed to.  I also found adding a single coordinate to the first axis, adding `scale only axis`, and explicitly setting the `ymin`, and `ymax` to both axes also helped to get the legend right.  Thanks for your help.  It's looking good now.

Comment: @Stewart,  nice to hear that you finally you get what you after! I add your finding to my answer.